# Cannot log in to the Stack Exchange app

Tags: support, login, android-app

I installed the Stack Exchange Android app, but I cannot login with my Stack Overflow account (it is not recognized as a Stack Exchange account). How can I make/upgrade my Stack OVerflow login/account so I can use the Android app?

**Note 1**: I don't have a separate Stack Exchange account, but from the app description the app should grant access to any of the Stack Exchange sub-sites, only that it doesn't without opening a global account.

**Note 2**: Another option which I am not sure of, that I read in other posts here, is to go ahead and open the Stack Exchange account with the same OpenID I use for Stack Overflow and the system will recognize the similarity and merge the accounts into one. I need confirmation if this is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use a Yahoo OpenID to login, you should be able to tap "Log in using another OpenID" on the login page and tap the "Yahoo" button.

There is no difference between a Stack Exchange login account and a Stack Overflow login account. The same login information you use on Stack Overflow can be used on any other one of our sites, the only difference is that you will be starting off as a new user (limited privileges) on each new site you join.

Comment: Yes I should be able to login, but as I explained, the app does not recognize it and wants me to create a new StackExchange account.

Comment: @ilomambo What's it exactly saying? It should not be asking you to make a new account. It might be an error on Yahoo's side. You can also [add a Stack Exchange OpenId](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) as you mentioned and use that.

Comment: I select "login using another OpenId", and I choose Yahoo. Then it says: "This login is new to Stack Exchange" and below that there is an orange button that says "Confirm and create a new account"

Comment: @ilomambo Are you using the same e-mail address you're using to login with on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes, the exact same login. In StackOverflow I also use Yahoo! with the same email address.

Comment: @ilomambo Please add a Stack Exchange OpenID to your account to login, I don't know why your Yahoo OpenID isn't working but that will work.

Comment: OK, how do I add Stack Exchange OpenID to my account? Some link with explanations or steps would be helpful. When I go to "my logins" from my StackOverflow page the Yahoo! OpenId is already there.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials - Hit "My Logins" then hit the "Add More" button on the bottom left.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to add a login but it required to open a new Stack Exchange account, so I cave down and opened a new account, tired of dealing with this. Thanks again.